# How to make an object (SKSprite node) disappear on click

Tags: ios, swift

I want the node to disappear when I click on the object. The object is moving around the screen and currently is removed when you click anywhere on the screen. However, I want it to be removed only when the object has been clicked on.

The code is as follows:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

struct Physics {
    static let Enemy: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
    let BorderCategory : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
    let BottomCategory : UInt32 = 0x1 << 3
    let BallCategory   : UInt32 = 0x1 << 4

}

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var Enemy = SKSpriteNode()
    var gameStarted = Bool()
    var gameState = "running"
    var destX : CGFloat = 0.0
    var destY : CGFloat = 0.0
    var score = 0

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
        borderBody.friction = 0
        self.physicsBody = borderBody
        Enemy.name = "Enemys"

        Enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "red2")
        Enemy.size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 70)
        Enemy.position = (CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 6 - Enemy.frame.width, y: self.frame.height / 10))

        Enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: Enemy.frame.height / 2)
        Enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Physics.Enemy
        //Enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Physics.Ground | Physics.wall
        //Enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Physics.Ground | Physics.wall
        Enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        Enemy.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        Enemy.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
        Enemy.physicsBody?.friction = 0
        Enemy.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
        Enemy.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0


        self.addChild(Enemy)
        let force = SKAction.applyForce(CGVector(dx: 300, dy: 300) , duration: 0.1)
        Enemy.run(force)
    }


    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first as UITouch!
        let touchLocation = touch?.location(in: self)
        let targetNode = atPoint(touchLocation!) as! SKSpriteNode
        if(targetNode.name == "Enemys"){
        Enemy.removeFromParent()
        }

    }
```

Comment: The problem is that your touch is on a single point on the screen. The chances that this point is _exactly_ the same as the position of the sprite is small to say the least...

Answer (score 0):

I personally find that the easiest way to handle this is to subclass SKSpriteNode and dig into the fact that it is descendant of `UIResponder`.

```
class AlienSprite: SKSpriteNode {
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

You also need to set the `isUserInteractionEnabled = true` on the instance somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You have to determine which node is under the touch, `SKNode` has methods about this: `nodeAtPoint` and `nodesAtPoint`:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first as UITouch!
    let touchLocation = touch?.location(in: self)
    if let hit = yourRootNode.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation) {
      if hit.name=="Enemy" {
         hit.removeFromParent();
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case what would be my rootnode? Sorry, I'm very new to swift. I tried to set my root node to 'Enemy' but it gives me a message saying 'initialiser for conditional binding must have operation type, not SKNode'

Comment: Your SKScene? Something appropriate that contains your enemy.